# angular 9 fails to bind when aot compile is used

Tags: angular

doing a normal `ng build` is fine. When I do `ng build --aot` I receive a number of errors. The main one though is the following, and I'm hoping the others will have a similar answer:

> error NG8002: can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'
>
> [(ngModel)]="value"

in my ts file I have:

```
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';
    
@Component({
      selector: 'stock-input',
      template: `
          <input
            id="stockid"
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            name="stockid"
            maxlength="13"
            [(ngModel)]="value"
            (blur)="touch()"
            (keyup)="change()"
            (change)="change()"
            #autofocus
          />
      `,
```

Every where I look, it says that I should be making a reference to FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule. Both are imported in my app.module.ts file.

Comment: @ bilpor, Can you please remove the **name** attribute then try. I think it will work.

Comment: @pavankumar I just tried, but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Can you please provide any stackblitz link with your code.

Comment: @pavankumar I cant I'm afraid. I'm in the middle of porting Angular 4 to Angular 9. I'm pulling files over in a controlled way and trying to resolve issues as I go. So it's not in a workable state at the moment, but should still compile. Which is the issue i'm having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the inline html declared in the template cannot be set this way. Placing the html into it's own file and referencing it in the form:

```
template: './mytemplatename.html',
```

resolves the `ng build --aot` issue.

Comment: Hi, does that mean earlier the HTML was inline in TS file and now you kept them in html file? I have HTMLS Already in another file but still getting this error in AOT build

Comment: @user1312242 in my answer above where I specify 'template' change this to 'templateUrl'